# Objective C new Header File marked with gray icon and cannot import Frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to Xcode and Objective so I may be doing something stupid now but I haven't been able to find a solution to the following problem:

1) I create a new header file in which I want to import a framework (DrobboxSDK.h)
2) The icon for the file is darker than the other files
3) I can't import the Dropbox header using <> nor does it autocomplete it for me (as it does with *all* other *existing* files...

what am I doing wrong? How come that all the previous files can import the framework?

I ve tried to add a build phase in the Build Phases dialogue as some tutorial suggested but the submenu in the build phase is greyed out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dark icon means that you have unsaved changes in that file.
If you can't import the sdk in other classes too, then make sure that you have set correct Header Search Path.

Also, Xcode has a bug with autocompletion in some cases, so just write yourself
`#import <DropboxSDK/DropboxSDK.h>`

Comment: The problem is not the autocomplete, I think this is just an indication. I can't build the project because the new header cannot import the framework

Comment: Then make sure that you have set correct Header search paths and Framework search paths

Comment: But it's already working with the previous files. Aren't the search paths global, that is, apply for all files ?

Comment: only in this new file I create, I get:
<DropboxSDK/DropboxSDK.h> file not found

Comment: OK, so when I create a new .m file I can import the Dropbox framework, but what I do with the header file? I need to import it there so that my class can inherit from DBRestClient

Comment: Hmm. Very strange. Try to delete that file and create again. Also delete DropboxSDK and follow this steps again: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/ios

Answer (score 0):

So I set up the header search path in the build settings and now I can import it...
Still don't know why I could already do that only with .m files before setting the path...